Git pages image display error even though path checked
I'm making Jekyll based GitHub pages now.
What was the problems that image is not displayed?
And there's trial and error I've been through.

I used imagemagick Jekyll plugin that it helps to change the image size automatically.


I did check _site/assets/img/.webp was correctly made.


relative path setting


I check my html file and figure.html and its path was fine additionally, https://username.github.io/assets/img/image_name.jpg directly display was fine.


in my post markdown file,

---
layout: page
title: title....
img: assets/img/figure1.png
importance: 1
--- <figure style="text-align: center;">
  <img src="{{ '/assets/img/figure2.png' | relative_url }}" alt="Process diagram">
  <figcaption style="font-style: italic; color: #555;">Figure 2: caption </figcaption>
</figure>


In those markdown file figure 1 was not displayed but figure 2 displayed well.

check _config.yml

url: https://username.github.io # the base hostname & protocol for your site
baseurl:
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Responsive WebP Images
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

imagemagick:
  enabled: true
  widths:
    - 480
    - 800
    - 1400
  input_directories:
    - /assets/img/
  input_formats:
    - ".jpg"
    - ".jpeg"
    - ".png"
    - ".tiff"
  output_formats:
    webp: "-quality 75%"

I did set my responsive webP images.

offcourse in my local serve everything was fine.


additionally, I found out that the problem only when the page window resized width. of course local build all image displayed well depending on the page width size.
